# select between record with temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image: record snap with query]

> i want to show tariff with feb month record with date serial
>   if tariff not available in month then show with previous tariff 
>   please see snapshot for more clarification

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_MonthlyReactiveCharge_Report] @Dateset date
```

AS
  SET DATEFIRST 1
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @Day int
    DECLARE @fromDt date
    DECLARE @endDate date
    DECLARE @finalEndDate date
    DECLARE @currentdate date = GETDATE()
    SET @fromDt = CAST(CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(YEAR, @Dateset)) + '-' + CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(MONTH, @Dateset)) + '-01' AS date)

```
SET @endDate = DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @fromDt) + 1, 0))
IF @endDate >= @currentdate
BEGIN
  SET @finalEndDate = DATEADD(D, -DATEDIFF(D, @currentdate, @endDate) - 1, @endDate);
  SET @Day = FORMAT(@finalEndDate, 'dd')
END
ELSE
  SET @finalEndDate = @endDate
SET @Day = FORMAT(@finalEndDate, 'dd')
SET NOCOUNT ON;

PRINT @fromDt;
PRINT @finalEndDate;
IF 1 = 0
BEGIN
  SET FMTONLY OFF
END
IF 1 = 0
BEGIN
  SET FMTONLY OFF
END
CREATE TABLE #TestTable2 (
  tempdate date
);

BEGIN
  DECLARE @VarDate datetime = CONVERT(date, @FromDt)
  WHILE @VarDate <= CONVERT(varchar, @finalEndDate)
  BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #TestTable2 (tempdate)
      VALUES (@VarDate)
    SET @VarDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @VarDate)
  END
  BEGIN
    WITH tarifReactivelow
    AS (SELECT
      b.tariffrate AS TRL,
      b.EFFECTIVEFROMDATE AS TRLeffectivefrmdate,
      b.effectivetodate AS TRLeffectivetodate,
      a.tempdate
    FROM (SELECT
      *
    FROM #TestTable2) a
    RIGHT JOIN T_EMS_REVENUE_TARIFFDETAILS b
      ON b.TARIFFTYPE = 10
      AND b.REACTIVECHARGETYPE = 2
      AND (
      (a.tempdate BETWEEN CONVERT(date, EFFECTIVEFROMDATE) AND CONVERT(date, EFFECTIVETODATE))
      OR (a.tempdate BETWEEN CONVERT(date, EFFECTIVEFROMDATE) AND CONVERT(date, EFFECTIVETODATE)
      OR CONVERT(date, EFFECTIVEFROMDATE) <= a.tempdate)

      ))
    SELECT
      *
    FROM tarifReactivelow
  END
  DROP TABLE #TestTable2
END
```

END

Comment: please don't [post images of code or text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361481/57475)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the most recent row that is less than or equal to the `tempdate` using `top 1` and [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

something like this:

```
select *
from #testtable2 as tt
  outer apply (
    select top 1 td.*
    from t_ems_revenue_tariffdetails as td
    where td.tarifftype=10
      and td.reactivechargetype=2
      and td.effectivefromdate<=tt.tempdate
    order by td.effectivefromdate desc
  ) x
```

[Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3) - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)